# Working on an assignment, alert displaying opposite of intended result

Tags: javascript, function, object, alert, console.log

Disclaimer: I'm very new to JS

Hi,

I'm working on an assignment in the form of a card game. Looking at the instructions, I'm correctly getting the following in the console:

```
User flipped queen
images/queen-of-hearts.png
hearts
User flipped king
images/king-of-hearts.png
hearts
```

The instructions also say that loading the html file should show the alert, "Sorry, try again."

*However, the alert I'm getting is "You found a match!" even though the two chosen cards don't.*

I figured it's probably something obvious, but I'm not sure as to what it could be.

Here's the code:

```
console.log('up and running');

var cards = [

{
rank: 'queen',
suit: 'hearts',
cardImage: 'images/queen-of-hearts.png',
},

{
rank: 'queen',
suit: 'diamonds',
cardImage: 'images/queen-of-diamonds.png',
},

{
rank: 'king',
suit: 'hearts',
cardImage: 'images/king-of-hearts.png',
},

{
rank: 'king',
suit: 'diamonds',
cardImage: 'images/king-of-diamonds.png',
}

];

var cardsInPlay = [];

var checkForMatch = function() {
    if (cardsInPlay.length === 2) 
        checkForMatch();

        if (cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) {
                alert('You found a match!');
            } else {
                alert('Sorry, try again.');
    }   
};

checkForMatch();



var flipCard = function(cardId) {
    console.log("User flipped " + cards[cardId].rank);

    console.log(cards[cardId].cardImage);
    console.log(cards[cardId].suit);

    cardsInPlay.push(cards[cardId].rank);
}



flipCard(0);
flipCard(2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Two observations:**

- You're calling the function `checkForMatch` before the call of `flipCard` function.
- You don't need to call the `checkForMatch` function when `length == 2`

```js
console.log('up and running');

var cards = [

  {
    rank: 'queen',
    suit: 'hearts',
    cardImage: 'images/queen-of-hearts.png',
  },

  {
    rank: 'queen',
    suit: 'diamonds',
    cardImage: 'images/queen-of-diamonds.png',
  },

  {
    rank: 'king',
    suit: 'hearts',
    cardImage: 'images/king-of-hearts.png',
  },

  {
    rank: 'king',
    suit: 'diamonds',
    cardImage: 'images/king-of-diamonds.png',
  }

];

var cardsInPlay = [];

var checkForMatch = function() {
  //if (cardsInPlay.length === 2)
    //checkForMatch();
console.log(cardsInPlay)
  if (cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) {
    alert('You found a match!');
  } else {
    alert('Sorry, try again.');
  }
};


var flipCard = function(cardId) {
  console.log("User flipped " + cards[cardId].rank);

  console.log(cards[cardId].cardImage);
  console.log(cards[cardId].suit);

  cardsInPlay.push(cards[cardId].rank);
}

flipCard(0);
flipCard(2);

checkForMatch();
```

**Happy coding!**

Comment: That did it thanks! Seeing the checkForMatch function after the flipCard ones makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the problem (and a potential issue). I've added a few comments to your code, I'd recommend reading them in order (see the number in each comment).

```
console.log('up and running');

var cards = [

{
rank: 'queen',
suit: 'hearts',
cardImage: 'images/queen-of-hearts.png',
},

{
rank: 'queen',
suit: 'diamonds',
cardImage: 'images/queen-of-diamonds.png',
},

{
rank: 'king',
suit: 'hearts',
cardImage: 'images/king-of-hearts.png',
},

{
rank: 'king',
suit: 'diamonds',
cardImage: 'images/king-of-diamonds.png',
}

];

var cardsInPlay = [];

var checkForMatch = function() {
    // 2 - Are there two flipped cards?
    //     No, because there are no cards in play yet
    if (cardsInPlay.length === 2) 
        checkForMatch();

    // 3 - I think that 'if' is missing a curly brace!
    //     So the follow code runs:

        // 4 - undefined === undefined
        if (cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) {
                // 5 - Match!
                alert('You found a match!');
            } else {
                alert('Sorry, try again.');
    }   
};

// 1 - This runs before any cards are flipped
checkForMatch();



var flipCard = function(cardId) {
    console.log("User flipped " + cards[cardId].rank);

    console.log(cards[cardId].cardImage);
    console.log(cards[cardId].suit);

    cardsInPlay.push(cards[cardId].rank);
}



flipCard(0);
flipCard(2);
```

Note that if you add the missing curly brace at `3` (and another to close it), you'll have an infinite loop! Because `checkForMatch()` infinitely call itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is two-fold:

1. You call `checkForMatch()` before actually flipping either card. Thus, you end up `undefined` and `undefined` for `cardsInPlay[0]` and `cardsInPlay[1]`. Because `undefined` === `undefined`, the game considers it to be a match. To resolve this, call your `checkForMatch()` function **after** your two `flipCard()` calls.
2. Now that the function call is moved, you get into an infinite loop. This is because `checkForMatch()` calls itself when there are two cards in play... and you never change the number of cards in play. To resolve this, remove the inner reference to `checkForMatch()`, and simply run your second `if` condition inside of the first check that there are two cards. This way, it only compares the card values when there are two cards.

This can be seen in the following working example:

```js
console.log('up and running');

var cards = [{
    rank: 'queen',
    suit: 'hearts',
    cardImage: 'images/queen-of-hearts.png',
  },
  {
    rank: 'queen',
    suit: 'diamonds',
    cardImage: 'images/queen-of-diamonds.png',
  },
  {
    rank: 'king',
    suit: 'hearts',
    cardImage: 'images/king-of-hearts.png',
  },
  {
    rank: 'king',
    suit: 'diamonds',
    cardImage: 'images/king-of-diamonds.png',
  }
];

var cardsInPlay = [];

var checkForMatch = function() {
  if (cardsInPlay.length === 2) {
    if (cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) {
      alert('You found a match!');
    } else {
      alert('Sorry, try again.');
    }
  }
};

var flipCard = function(cardId) {
  console.log("User flipped " + cards[cardId].rank);
  console.log(cards[cardId].cardImage);
  console.log(cards[cardId].suit);
  cardsInPlay.push(cards[cardId].rank);
}

flipCard(0);
flipCard(2);

checkForMatch();
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the check function before the flip function. In the check function both index return undefined value and this of course equal.